# Drawing an affine plane in latex

Tags: tikz-pgf, labels, nodes, graphs

I was trying to draw the following "graph" (affine plane) in tex:

[image]

I made some tries and I have the current code:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{
node distance=3cm, % specifies the minimum distance between two nodes. Change if necessary.
every node/.style={circle,thin, fill=black}, % sets the properties for each ’state’ node
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[label = $1$] (1) {};
    \node[label = $2$,right of=1] (2) {};
    \node[label = $3$,right of=2] (3) {};
    \node[label = $4$,below of=1] (4) {};
    \node[label = $5$,below of=2] (5) {};
    \node[label = $6$,below of=3] (6) {};
    \node[label = $7$,below of=4] (7) {};
    \node[label = $8$,below of=5] (8) {};
    \node[label = $9$,below of=6] (9) {};
    \draw[-]
    (1) edge[green] (2)
    (2) edge[green] (3)
    (4) edge[red] (5)
    (5) edge[red] (6)
    (7) edge[purple] (8)
    (8) edge[purple] (9)
    (3) edge[yellow] (5)
    (5) edge[yellow] (7)
    (1) edge[gray] (5)
    (5) edge[gray] (9)
    (3) edge[blue] (6)
    (6) edge[blue] (9)
    (1) edge[cyan] (4)
    (4) edge[cyan] (7)
    (2) edge[pink] (5)
    (5) edge[pink] (8)
    (2) edge[dashed] (4)
    (4) edge[dashed, bend right = 50, looseness = 2] (9); 

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Which gives me the following output:

[image]

Basically, I am having a hard time curving the edges and positioning the labels correctly. Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: without using `edge`, you can use `control`, see its usage in the pgfmanual https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a start (with a different node style to avoid the lines through the numbers).

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{
node distance=3cm, % specifies the minimum distance between two nodes. Change if necessary.
every node/.style={circle,thin,draw=black}, % sets the properties for each ’state’ node
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node(1) {$1$};
    \node[right of=1] (2) {$2$};
    \node[right of=2] (3) {$3$};
    \node[below of=1] (4) {$4$};
    \node[below of=2] (5) {$5$};
    \node[below of=3] (6) {$6$};
    \node[below of=4] (7) {$7$};
    \node[below of=5] (8) {$8$};
    \node[below of=6] (9) {$9$};
    \draw[-]
    (1) edge[green] (2)
    (2) edge[green] (3)
    (4) edge[red] (5)
    (5) edge[red] (6)
    (7) edge[purple] (8)
    (8) edge[purple] (9)
    (3) edge[yellow] (5)
    (5) edge[yellow] (7)
    (1) edge[gray] (5)
    (5) edge[gray] (9)
    (3) edge[blue] (6)
    (6) edge[blue] (9)
    (1) edge[cyan] (4)
    (4) edge[cyan] (7)
    (2) edge[pink] (5)
    (5) edge[pink] (8)
    (2) edge[dashed] (4)
    (4) edge[dashed, out=225, in=225, looseness=2] (9); 

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```